# Cant understand why do i get 403 while trying to setup phpmyadmin with nginx on ubunu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

So the problem is when i try to run phpmyadmin on nginx i get 403.

error log of nginx says:

> directory index of "var/www/html" is forbidden

and the server config looks like that:
[server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0q4z.png)

i've looked through the whole internet, and each and every anwser doesn't seem to help in any way. Thanks for help in advance

Also when I try to access http://domain/phpmyadmin/index.php my browser just downloads index.php file, instead of opening the login page